# How to handle remove from DOM effect?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that is being rendered based upon a condition:

```
{{#if boolean}}
  {view MyView}}
{{/if}}
```

I can easily add a nice animation for when the element is inserted into the DOM:

```
MyView: {
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().hide().show('slide', {direction: 'left', duration: 2000});
  }
}
```

However, the same cannot be done when the element is removed from the DOM:

```
MyView: {
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().hide('slide', {direction: 'right', duration: 2000});
  }
}
```

This does not work because the element is being shown based upon a condition that is beyond this view's control the element is removed from the DOM immediately. The async animation never runs.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case, you might instead bind your boolean to your view and observe it, hiding and showing the view manually, but otherwise leaving it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky solution, but works for me:

```
willDestroyElement: ->
  element = @$().clone()
  @$().replaceWith element
  element.slideUp 250, ->
    element.remove()
```

Basically, clone the DOM element, let Ember destroy the element associated with the view, and do the animation with the clone (being sure to destroy the clone after the animation is complete)

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like this on your view?

```
booleanChanged: function() {
  var boolean = this.get('controller.boolean');
  if (boolean) {
    this.$().hide().show('slide', {direction: 'left', duration: 2000});
  } else {
    this.$().hide('slide', {direction: 'right', duration: 2000});
  }
}.observes('controller.boolean')
```

and just use in your handelbar

```
{view MyView}}
```